# How to get order details from DB, using order id in frontend in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.2

I need to fetch Order details from core table(sale_order_status_history) using order id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Object Manager Instance**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($IncrementId); //Use increment id here.
$order->getCustomerName();
```

**Using Blocks**

*You need to inject `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` class to get order status
Add following code in your block*

```
protected $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        ...
    }

    public function getOrder($orderId)
    {
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);

        return $order;
    }
```

**Call function in your .phtml**

```
$orderId = 1; //Order Id
$order = $block->getOrder($orderId); 
// Check all order data using debug \Zend_Debug::dump($order->debug());
$order->getCustomerName();
```

Comment: @Jayashree is this solution helpful to you ?